# Set performance counter value with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

Is there a way to **set** the value of a performance counter using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.

```
$counter = (New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter -ArgumentList ("CategoryName", "CounterName", "InstanceName", $false))    
$counter.RawValue = 0
```

Comment: Nice, though you can simplify the first statement: neither the parentheses nor the quotes are needed: `$counter = New-Object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter CategoryName, CounterName, InstanceName, $false`